# How to access properties on objects stored in UserDefaults

Tags: swift

I Want To Access "fullname" In User Array In UserDefaults By This Statement

```
Optional({ message = Hello; success = true; user = { fullname = "xyz"; id = 0; }; })
```

```
if currentUser?[""] != nil {

// do something 
}
```

Comment: please do not put code as the title for your question. you need to update your question and make it clear what you are asking before the community votes to close this question

Comment: This isn't enough information to understand with what you need help. Please provide background information, detailed and precise explanations for what your are trying to do and what outcome you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Let assume that the optional: `Optional({ message = Hello; success = true; user = { fullname = “xyz”; id = 0; }; })` is set as `currentUser`:

```
if let currentUser = currentUser { //get a not optional value of currentUser
    let fullname = currentUser["fullname"] //you will get an optional here
    if fullname != nil {
       print("Full name: \(fullname!)")
    } else {
       print("Full name wasn't provided")
    }
}
```

but the same you could provide in one line check:

```
if let currentUser = currentUser, let fullname = currentUser["fullname"] {
    print("Full name: \(fullname)"
}
```

more about optionals you can read in documents: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional or in some blog posts, I'm recommending this one: https://hackernoon.com/swift-optionals-explained-simply-e109a4297298

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**

**Store**

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "Key") //Bool
UserDefaults.standard.set(1, forKey: "Key")  //Integer
UserDefaults.standard.set("TEST", forKey: "Key") //setObject
```

**Retrieve**

```
UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "Key")
UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Key")
UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Key")
```

**Retrive Object**

```
var returnValue: [datatype]? = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "key_name") as? [datatype]
```

**Remove**

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "Key")
```

**Remove all Keys**

```
if let appDomain = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier {
UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: appDomain)
}
```